# Forcing read_delim in readr to treat multiple " and \ as part of column string

Tags: r, csv, import, special-characters, readr

Given a **`;`** delimited file of structure:

```
colA; colB; colC
1;A; 10
2;B; 11     
3;C"; 12
4;D""; 15
5;"F";20
6;K"""; 21
7;""M";22
8; \""O;23
```

I would like to ensure that **`colB`** is always imported verbatim as a character string. In particular, I would like to preserve all values including `""M"` and `\""O`.

## Attempt

I'm currently trying:

```
require(readr)
tst_dta <- read_delim(
  file = "test_file.csv",
  escape_double = FALSE,
  delim = ";",
  col_types = cols(
    colA = col_integer(),
    colB = col_character(),
    colC = col_integer()
  )
)
```

but this returns:

```
> tst_dta
# A tibble: 8 x 3
   colA colB        colC
  <int> <chr>      <int>
1     1 A             10
2     2 B             NA
3     3 "C\""         12
4     4 "D\"\""       15
5     5 F             20
6     6 "K\"\"\""     21
7     7 "\"\"M\""     22
8     8 " \\\"\"O"    23
```

## Desired rsults

The desired results should reflect:

```
    colA colB  colC
   <int> <chr> <int>
    1     A     10
    2     B     11     
    3     C"    12
    4     D""   15
    5    "F"    20
    6     K"""  21
    7   ""M"    22
    8  \""O     23
```

---

## Other points:

- Ideally, I would also like to ensure that non-ASCII characters are ignored in a manner that value `\""[Non-ASCII-Character]O`would appear in the resulting data frame as `\""O` string.

---

## Updates

As per comments, more examples:

*is:*

```
colA; colB; colC
1; text \" text; 2
```

*should be:*

```
colA;colB;colC
1;text text;2
```

*is:*

```
colA; colB; colC
1; text \;" text; 2
```

*should be:*

```
colA;colB;colC
1;text text;2
```

*is:*

```
colA; colB; colC
1; [non-ASCII] text something \;" text; 2
```

*should be:*

```
colA;colB;colC
1;text something;2
```

Comment: not possible, or reasonable in my opinion.

Comment: @AndreElrico Broadly speaking, I would tend to agree on the *reasonable* point, but expectedly, I'm doing this out of necessity not out of choice. Happy to consider answer that will get me as close as possible to the desired results, i.e maintain column structure, drop non-ASCII characters and salvage rest of the data to greatest possible extent.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can have `"` inside a character string without escaping. Why  do you need it without escapement?

Comment: count me as interessted in a solution!

Comment: @AndreElrico You mean in the input file? The file appeared to "suffer" some manual transformations with odd `"` and non-ASCII characters inserted on random. In a word, the key goal is to preserve as much file as possible.

Comment: can you post real data examples where something "wrong" happened and what it really should be instead?

Comment: @AndreElrico Updated with some more examples

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173567/discussion-between-andre-elrico-and-konrad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `readr`-functions, then look at it's argument list and see if it has an equivalent to the `quote` argument in `read.table` (which allows simple access:

```
 read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE, quote="", sep=";")
  colA colB colC
1    1    A   10
2    2    B   11
3    3   C"   12
4    4  D""   15
5    5  "F"   20
6    6 K"""   21
7    7 ""M"   22
8    8  ""O   23
```

Seems like it should succeed, since it's the third argument in `readr::read_delim`. The default in both cases is `"\""` which is a single double-quote. Set it to an empty character (`""`):

## Usage

```
read_delim(file, delim, quote = "\"", escape_backslash = FALSE,
  escape_double = TRUE, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL,
  locale = default_locale(), na = c("", "NA"), quoted_na = TRUE,
  comment = "", trim_ws = FALSE, skip = 0, n_max = Inf,
  guess_max = min(1000, n_max), progress = show_progress())
```

And this is the print representation of the result. I would note that this print representation seems bit irregular. Character values are enclosed in double quotes *only* if they have embedded double quotes, i.e `\"`. On the other hand such columns *are* character which is a nice change from the default settings in read.table which give you factor columns:

```
read_delim(file=txt,  quote="", delim=";")
# A tibble: 8 x 3
   colA ` colB`   ` colC`   
  <int> <chr>     <chr>     
1     1 A         " 10"     
2     2 B         " 11     "
3     3 "C\""     " 12"     
4     4 "D\"\""   " 15"     
5     5 "\"F\""   20        
6     6 "K\"\"\"" " 21"     
7     7 "\"\"M\"" 22        
8     8 " \"\"O"  23
```

You are hereby warned that using this option with `read_delim` does mean that neither column names nor values are trimmed to remove whitespace. And *everything* is `character`, even the columns that would otherwise come in as `character`. Notice the name of your second column. That does not occur with `read.table`:

```
read_delim(file=txt,  quote="", delim=";")$` colB` == 
         read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE, quote="", sep=";")$colB
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Further `gsub`-processing would be needed if you wanted leading or trailing whitespace to be removed. `rm_non_ascii` in pkg {qdapRegex} can remove non-ASCII characters